# KOMA-Script: Making Preface Page Like Chapter

Tags: fonts, hyperref, chapters, koma-script

I am finishing setting up my thesis LaTeX document using `scrreprt` class.

I am trying to add the final touches which include a `List of Acronyms`. Now I want it to look exactly the same as the `ToC` does in style as far as the title "List of Acronyms" goes. I have managed to do this by using `\chapter*{List of Acronyms}` whereby it uses the chapter style without printing a chapter page, and here is where the problem arises, when I do this the page numbering is automatically switched to `arabic`; I wish for the LoA to be in the preface which should all be in `roman` page numbering.

How can I use the exact same style of the chapter* font for the title (which also omits it from the ToC which is fine) without losing the roman page numbering?

Please find below my MWE with included an acronym (**side note** if someone could also direct me to a post which explains how to customise the `\printacronyms` format I would be very grateful).

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % list subsubsections

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ACRONYM DEFINITION
\DeclareAcronym{pwr}{
short = PWR ,
short-plural = s ,
long = Pressurised Water Reactor ,
long-plural = s ,
class = reactors ,
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\cleardoublepage
\dominitoc
\pdfbookmark[1]{Contents}{}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LIST OF ACRONYMS
\chapter*{List of Acronyms}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms}

\printacronyms[include-classes=reactors,name=Reactor Acronyms]

\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Chapter Style Controls
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft \linespread{1}}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{20}{11}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{18}{11}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{16}{11}\selectfont}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{0.80}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{2.5}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}

\chapter{Testing}

Pasting an acronym \ac{pwr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Other than adding again `\pagenumbering{roman}` (and probably increasing the counter) I cannot say. But some other things: Why the first `\cleardoublepage` _before_ any output? Already asked in a comment to another question: Why do you load `setspace`, when you do not use it?

Comment: Also take a look on `\addchap*` in KOMA-Script doc.

Comment: @Speravir life saver as always. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`) command after `\printacronyms`; otherwise, the `\pagenumbering{arabic}` will take effect too soon.

As **Speravir** mentions in his comment, the KOMA classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt` offer `\addchap`, (and a starred version `\addchap*`) which can produce unnumbered chapters which show up in the table of contents and in the running heading (the starred version doesn't show up in the headings), so instead of

```
\chapter*{List of Acronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
```

you can simply use, for example,

```
\addchap{List of Acronyms}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[
bibliography=totoc,
headings=big,
captions=tableheading,
chapterprefix=true% like in standard class "report"
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % list subsubsections

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ACRONYM DEFINITION
\DeclareAcronym{pwr}{
short = PWR ,
short-plural = s ,
long = Pressurised Water Reactor ,
long-plural = s ,
class = reactors ,
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\cleardoublepage %<- seems not necessary
\dominitoc
\pdfbookmark[1]{Contents}{}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LIST OF ACRONYMS
%\chapter*{List of Acronyms}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
\addchap{List of Acronyms}
\printacronyms[include-classes=reactors,name=Reactor Acronyms]
\clearpage

\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Chapter Style Controls
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft \linespread{1}}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{20}{11}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{18}{11}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{16}{11}\selectfont}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{0.80}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{2.5}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}

\chapter{Testing}

Pasting an acronym \ac{pwr}

\end{document}
```

Section **7.3. Options Regarding the List** of the package decumentation has some explanations regarding options and customization of the list.

Comment: Hey, you’re mean, I already had upvoted. ;-)

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, Thank you for the explanation and also supplement information for the acronym list. Have a nice day